# Are there any issues of using Master Page for professional website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I am beginner and I have to build a professional website from scratch. So, i am confused either to use "Master Page" or Not! I heard about complexity of Master Pages. What should i do???

Comment: Try and Try again and then again thats what you should do

Comment: In a simple fast answer: "use master pages"

Comment: " I heard about complexity of Master Pages. " What did you hear?

Comment: Depends, if want all pages to have the same look, use masterpages and it will speed up development in the end and when editing pages.

Comment: Wherever you heard that, discard the source as unreliable at once...

Answer (score 1):

Master Pages allow you to specify a common layout for your web application that can be inherited from.

If you have a common page structure within your application, using Master Pages will prevent you having to duplicate markup and logic on **each and every** page.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a master page as a skeleton for all pages that inherit from it.

You simply define the layout that you want all pages to have the same, (such as navigation bar / logo / side panel / main page content area)

By creating a master page it means that you have the basic structure ready to hand for all pages that inherit from it (which takes 1 line)

Depending on whether you are using MVC or forms based the syntax is different but the idea is still the same. It is VERY useful to use master pages, as they reduce code during development. In a master page you must define the page area for the pages.